# GIT implementation in this scenario

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have a server machine lets say its X.
Two developers are working on this project on same local network. Lets say developers machines are A and B.

I want to implement GIT usage (via bitbucket and sourcetree). 
I have installed GIT at machine X, pushed code to GIT server successfully. But how these two developers from machine A and B can use GIT to push their changes.

Project is centrally placed at machine X.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Project is centrally placed at machine X.

If you really plan on using git with bitbucket, it is not.
From what you wrote I think your origin repository is located on the bitbucket servers.

Try to not think in centralized repositories like with SVN. X will have a git repository, A will have a repository, and B will too have a repository.
All of their changes will be committed to their local repositories.

Those repositories can then deliver/get/merge their changes with other repositories, for example the bitbucket server, by pushing or pulling commits.

What matters for A and B is the remote-origin settings of their local git repositories. You can set those to the bitbucket server, then the changes should be pushed there and X will then pull the changes again. Otherwise define the repository at X as remote-origin for A and B, then they will push to X instead.